# My pygame screen is not updating event with pygame.display.update

Tags: python, pygame

My pygame screen is not updating correctly and i am not sure why.

pygame code:

```
import pygame
import os 
import random
import time

pygame.init()

width = 750
height = 750
win = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Space attack')
bg_size = 750, 750

bg = pygame.image.load("/home/pi/Pygames/Space_attack/background-black.png")
image = pygame.transform.scale(bg, bg_size)

#ships
r_ship= pygame.image.load('/home/pi/Pygames/Space_attack/pixel_ship_red_small.png')
g_ship= pygame.image.load('/home/pi/Pygames/Space_attack/pixel_ship_green_small.png')
b_ship= pygame.image.load('/home/pi/Pygames/Space_attack/pixel_ship_blue_small.png')

#player
player = pygame.image.load('/home/pi/Pygames/Space_attack/pixel_ship_yellow.png')

#laser
r_laser = pygame.image.load('/home/pi/Pygames/Space_attack/pixel_laser_red.png')
b_laser = pygame.image.load('/home/pi/Pygames/Space_attack/pixel_laser_blue.png')
g_laser = pygame.image.load('/home/pi/Pygames/Space_attack/pixel_laser_green.png')
p_laser = pygame.image.load('/home/pi/Pygames/Space_attack/pixel_laser_yellow.png')

#game
def main():
    run = True
    fps = 30
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    
    def redraw_window():
        win.blit(bg, (0,0))
        
        pygame.display.update
    
    while run:
        clock.tick(fps)
        redraw_window()
        
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
                
main()
```

I have look on the internet and found nothing that works, I am new and this is my first pygame.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you try `pygame.init()` as init is a function and you havent called it.

Comment: Thanks for the idea put it is still not working.

Comment: Please provide an [example] by removing everything that is not necessary for the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Simply change `pygame.display.update` to `pygame.display.update()`
`pygame.display.update` does not *call* the function.
If you want to call the function, use `function_name(args)`.

Comment: There is a recommendation not to answer typo-question. Questions like these are off-topic and should not be answered but closed as they are not helpful to other contributors. The questions will be closed and finally deleted. If the question is deleted, your gained reputation points will be lost.v